Consulta tabla php que muestre filas con el espacio vacio
Estoy atorado en algo tan simple que no puedo resolverlo, es una consulta en la que quiero que me muestre solamente lo que sea departamento Calidad y que firma = vacio, osea que no se ha firmado, hice la consulta de esta manera y me funciona bien asi (muestra todo lo de Calidad).
$consulta="SELECT * FROM tarjetas WHERE departamento='Calidad' ";
                        $execute=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

Pero al colocar la consulta de esta manera me arroja nada, me muestra la tabla vacia
$consulta="SELECT * FROM tarjetas WHERE departamento='Calidad' AND firma_lider ='' ";
                        $execute=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

Dentro del html viene la tabla asi:
<?php while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['departamento'] ;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['firma_lider'] ;?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }?>

Esta es la imagen de la BD:

SOlo necesito me muestre los que aun no tengan registro en "firma_lider", alguien me pueda ayudar

'' no es lo mismo que NULL. Intenta con ... firma_lider IS NULL. Ver documentación

Listo, era solo eso muchas gracias funciono como debe de ser

A parte de la respuesta que ya te dieron, te recomiendo que leas sobre los "Prepared statements" ya bien sea para mysqli o para pdo. En tu caso, estás usando mysqli, así que informate un poco sobre "mysqli_stmt::bind_param" y "mysqli::prepare" (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) para hacer tu código algo más seguro de cara a sql injection.

NULL no es lo mismo que una cadena vacía (Curso de Base de Datos 101).
Para encontrar los registros que no tienen valor en el campo, debes usar el operador is null y no la comparación de igualdad con una cadena vacía.
Esta consulta obtendrá los registros que quieres:
SELECT * FROM tarjetas WHERE departamento='Calidad' AND firma_lider is null

Si por alguna razón también quieres incluir los registros que tengan una cadena vacía, la consulta sería:
SELECT * FROM tarjetas WHERE departamento='Calidad' AND (firma_lider is null or firma_lider = '')

Encontrarás más información en la documentación de NULL
